# Angularjs 1 App loading is very slow

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs for my wesite but for the first time loading a page is blank for 3000ms. [image]

How can I improve the performance? I am using these things in my project
(1)Angular js Ui -routes
(2)Grunt for Scss compile.
(3)bower for third-party library install.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is nearly impossible to answer with the information you have provided. You are only showing us a portion of what happens in the browser.

What version of angular are you on? Are you working in local, or are you showing data from a hosted version of your site? Please add the network tab...

How large is you application? How many routes, how many modules?

Are you using `ng-if` (good) instead of `ng-show/hide` (bad in most cases)? Are you using one-way binding inside your expressions what you know the data will never change? Do you have a lot of angular event emitters and watchers? Are you destroying your components/directives correctly?

As you can see, it's not a simple answer.